# Notepad++ Join indented lines

Tags: notepad++, whitespace, indentation

I have a formatted HTML file where block element are indented so there is typically whitespace at the start of each line.  If I join/merge multiple lines using CTRL+J it brings this whitespace with it.  For example if I join the 2 lines of my paragraph below...

```
<div>
    <p>first line of my paragraph.
    second line of my paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

I end up with

```
<div>
    <p>first line of my paragraph.    second line of my paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

(i.e a load of whitespace between the first "." and the word "second".)

Is there a way to have this white space automatically removed when I do the join either through a native command, a macro or a plugin?  I want to keep the whitespace used for indentation at the start of the top line (i.e. before the paragraph tag in the above example)

Thanks

Alan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any plugin for this.
But this can be done in two steps.

- Replace all leading space and tab to empty
- Select the lines and hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd>

**Search String :** ^[\s\t]*

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!  This works a treat.  I have recorded the two steps as a macro and assigned a shortcut to it so now I can do it with a single key combination.